# Statistics - Probability - Distributed Exponentially Proof

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Could anyone help me with the following proof, and give me any lead how to prove or refute this statement?

$X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. For each constant $a\ne 0$ and constant $b$, the random variable $Y = aX + b$ is distributed exponentially.

Thank You!

Comment: @Henry Edited the post:)

Comment: It would help if you write the definitions so that we are aware what you already know. What is the exact definition of $Exp$ and what does "distributed exponentially" precisely mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P(X \le x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x \ge  0$ and $P(X \le x) =0$ for $x \le 0$

and if $Y = aX+b$ with $a \gt 0$ so $P(Y \le y) = P(aX+b \le y) = P(X \le \frac{y}{a} -\frac{b}{a})$

then $P(Y \le y) = 1-e^{\frac{b\lambda}{a}}e^{- \frac{\lambda}{a}y}$ for $y \ge b$ and $P(Y \le y) =0$ for $y \le b$

If $b=0$, this simplifies to $P(Y \le y) = 1-e^{- \frac{\lambda}{a}y}$ for $y \ge 0$ and so is a exponential distribution with rate $\frac{\lambda}{a}$

Personally I would not call the distribution for $Y$ an *exponential* distribution if  $b\not=0$.  I might instead call it a *shifted exponential* distribution, or something similar.  And if $a <0$  then I might call it a *reversed exponential* distribution, or something similar.